# Why is drupal resizing my images?

Tags: views, media

In drupal I'm displaying a view in a block. I'm stripping out all the html and rewriting the results as this

```
<li><a href="#">[field_button_image]</a></li>
```

On the preview it looks okay, but in the block that contains the view it renders the image like this

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="image/image.png" width="200" height="240" alt="">
```

The image is distorted because of the width and height styling that is added in the tag. Where is this coming from? And is it possible to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your content type. what is default image type in manage field display. set it Original image. hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

The display setting of this field for the particular content type might be different from the original.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look in to your :

- block.tpl templates
- Or maybe a filter in the block or the user permissions
- Display mode of the node